# Sorting algorithm - in groups, weighted

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I will try to be as throughly as possible:

- I have 11 groups.
- I have a large number of people that need to be divided between those groups
- Each person has a weighted list of preferences. It is usual to have 3 groups, ordered, on that list, but a few outliers will have either more or less groups. IE:
  Person 1 have a preference for entering group A. If thats not avaliable, she would like to enter group D, and if that one is not avaliable she would like in on group C.
  Person 2 has no preferences for any group.
  Person 3 is only avaliable for group D.
- Groups have a maximum number. How large depends on the amount of people participating, but groups will have to be balanced.
- The ideal group distribution is one where the largest amount of preferences is realized.

So far, i got that i will need weighted preferences. 3, 2 1 for wights are a good start. The ideal group distribution is one where the sum of the preferences for people joining that group is as close as possible as that sum for people joining each other group.

No preference means weight 3 for all groups. At least until i fine tune it.

I have no idea on how to maka a algorithym to actually start sorting that though. help?

Comment: You could try all possible assignments, and see which has the highest score.  Not the fastest approach, certainly...

Comment: Did you have any particular programming language in mind?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a [weighted bipartite graph matching problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#In_weighted_bipartite_graphs)*, where one set of vertices represents the groups and the other set of vertices represents the people, and the edges have a weight of 0 (if the assignment isn't possible), or 10 / [number of preferences] x [number of preferences - preference number + 1] or something along those lines (so if a user has 5 preferences, their top preference would be weighted 10, their next would be 8, then 6, then 4, then 2)

You can clone the group vertices to fit the partitioning requirements (e.g. if a group can have up to 50 people in it, then create 50 copies of the group's vertex) and enforce one edge per vertex, which is what a lot of bipartite graph partitioning algorithms are designed to handle

Bipartite graph matching (both the weighted and unweighted version) is a polynomial time algrithm

*Classically known as a [(stable) marriage problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marriage_problem) - you have one set of vertices representing men, another set of vertices representing women, and a set of (weighted) edges expressing the marriage preferences of the two sets of vertices

Comment: Perhaps there is something in your idea, but in it's current state it will not work. Simple counterexample: if you have weighted edges between people vertices and group vertices, what will restrict people from taking more than one group?

Comment: I'm afraid that this task is NP unfortunately.

Comment: @Aivean The algorithm typically takes care of enforcing this restriction.  See for example [Hopcroft-Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm), which is O(V^2.5), and which enforces the restriction that no two edges share an endpoint (hence a person can only belong to one group)

Comment: Hopcroft-Karp is designed for non-weighted graphs. Obviously there is no such problem in unweighted graphs. I was thinking of using maximal flow to find maximum cardinality matching in weighted graph. And I'm really not sure that it is possible to modify some max flow algorithm in order to make it enforce desired restriction.

Comment: @Aivean A google search will reveal a plethora of polynomial time weighted bipartite graph matching algorithms, for example [this one](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~hsinhao/mwm_full.pdf).  Unless explicitly stated otherwise, all bipartite graph matching algorithms (weighted or otherwise) produce a result in which no vertex is connected by more than one edge - that's what the definition of a [maximum matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29) is.

Comment: Ok, it appears that you are right. Then I think your suggested solution will work. Thanks for pointing me at bipartite matching algorithms.